# JavaFXPorts and NetBeans Gluon Plugin

Tags: java, android, netbeans, javafx, javafxports

I'm getting following exception while building Javafx Application into Android.

```
error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'icon' with value '@mipmap/ic_launcher').

:processAndroidDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processAndroidDebugResources'.
> Process 'command 'E:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\23.0.1\aapt.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1 mins 24.005 secs



Build failure (see the Notifications window for stacktrace): gradle :android
```

and I'm had installed android sdk and pointed to `ANDROID_HOME`. this my build script in `build.gradle`.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b4'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.javafxports.jfxmobile'

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

mainClassName = 'com.javafxport.JavaFXPort'

jfxmobile {
    android {
        manifest = 'src/android/AndroidManifest.xml'
    }
    ios {
        infoPList = file('src/ios/Default-Info.plist')
    }
}
```

I'm trying to install very simple javafx application into my android device. please help me with advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, check that your Gluon plugin for NetBeans is updated. Currently you can use version 1.0.2, that will provide you with a more updated version of the plugin:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.0-b9'
}
```

Actually, according to [this](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/javafxmobile-plugin), you can update that manually to:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin:1.0.1'
}
```

Now check on Android SDK, using SDK Manager, that you have installed sdks version 22, and building tools version 22, but not version 23, which is for the new Android M, not supported yet by JavaFXPorts.